# How do I parse the remote server name inside echo when executing over ssh

Tags: ssh, echo, eof, hostname

I know the title is a bit confusing but there is no other way.

Script runs and connects to remote server over ssh. This is going to run on 500 servers thatswhy I 'd like to have an output like this on the console.

*echo " checking $hostname"* or *echo " checking ${hostname}"* returns nothing.
*echo " checking $(hostname)"* returns the hostname of the local server ironically.

```
ssh $Server /bin/bash <<EOF
install some software
echo "checking <remote-server-name> after installation"
java -version
groovy -v
jruby -v
EOF
```

I was just curious if this is doable actually.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `echo " checking $hostname" or echo " checking ${hostname}" returns nothing.`

That is expected. There is in general no such variable named `hostname`, so you wouldn't expect a result.  There is however a `HOSTNAME` variable, but that's only half the problem.

> echo " checking $(hostname)" returns the hostname of the local server ironically.

That's because when you use "here" document, as in

```
somecommand << EOF
...
EOF
```

The contents of the here document are evaluated for variable expansion before the input is fed to your command.  This is exactly why the `$(hostname)` construct is executing the `hostname` command on your local system.

You can inhibit the evaluation of the here document by quoting your end marker with single quotes, like this:

```
ssh $Server /bin/bash <<'EOF'
install some software
echo "checking $HOSTNAME after installation"
java -version
groovy -v
jruby -v
EOF
```

Comment: Wow, great answer man, thanx. Not that I'm a Bash-Guru but I have the feeling that no matter how much you learn, bash remains a mystery...
Cheers,
Dimi